QGIS exported PDF doesn't have the same linewidth as in the layout
Below are two images: the first is how my maps look in the layout window, and the second is how the PDF is exported.


I tried a suggested solution to define linewidth in millimeters and tampering with many of those PDF export settings, but to no avail.
Edit: these are my PDF export settings, I tried turning on and off "Always export as vectors", changing image compression, etc.

And the symbologies are like this


Please include the images in your post, thank you. Please also include the suggested solutions and/or your current settings.

Oh, ok, sorry. Done.

Because it is easy, I would run a check geometry on your layer(s) just to make sure you don't have a geometry issue which can create problems in an export.

How large is the layout you're exporting?

I ran the two layers that appear in the layout into "Check validity" and all geometries came out as valid.
The layout is a portrait A4 with 4 maps inside

I can't recreate your problem but it depends on how you are generating the darker outline on the outside. It might help if you share what the layer styling settings are for at least one of your maps. Do you have one layer with the individual polygons and one layer (different datasource) that is just the larger region as one polygon? Or is it the one datasource loaded twice, one styled as individual polygons and the other styled with the Merged Features renderer?
